# Secure Messenger in Java

Tags: java, security, networking

While creating a Secure Instant messenger in java , if there are many clients
for example
3 clients
client A,B,C
A wants to connect to B and C both. So do i need to create different socket connection for both of them separately?
If so than is not it is a restriction like if there are 10,000 clients and each wants to connect to rest of them so i will need million ports?

Comment: If you want to make two connections, then yes, you need two sockets.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, your solution would work. But when you add many more users, the instant messager will lag and be hard to maintain.

The better solution is to have one connection for each client, a connection to a server. clients will connect to this server (which will also handle authentication), and the server will sort out the messages and deliver them to another client(the messages destination).